# .net barcode generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode, code39

I am developing a barcode generating web application using asp.net/c#  ,I was wondering if it is better to use barcode library or a barcode font will be just enough.I have come across some samples but when using barcode font I found there is an asterisk(*) in front of the each code used for generating barcode.And I dint find any free barcode libraries. I want to generate code 39 or 93. Please help me decide

Comment: Barcode fonts are problematic in my experience...

Answer (score 0):

try [jquery-barcode](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/)

Its a javascript library to generate bar codes. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835082/394381) for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method I am using that doesn't require you to install the font:

```
public static Image GetBarCode(this string data, int fontSizeEm)
        {
            data = "*" + data + "*";
            Image img = null;
            Graphics drawing = null;
            try
            {
                using (var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection())
                {
                    pfc.AddFontFile(@"{{PATH TO YOUR FONT FILE}}");
                    using (var myfont = new Font(pfc.Families[0], fontSizeEm))
                    {
                        img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
                        var textSize = drawing.MeasureString(data, myfont);
                        img.Dispose();
                        drawing.Dispose();
                        img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int) textSize.Height);
                        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
                        drawing.DrawString(data, myfont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
                    }
                    drawing.Save();
                }
                return img;
            }
            catch
            {
                //Handle exception
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(drawing!= null)
                    drawing.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, libraries that generate barcodes via graphic primitives like rectangles are far superior to barcode fonts. Reasons:

- Fonts are much larger, often orders of magnitude, and take much longer to transmit. This is especially problematic on serial connections.
- The barcodes fonts produce are often less accurate as printers may try to anti-alias the bars.
- Fonts are subject to things like styles, word-wrapping, font substitution, and other effects that make them difficult to control.

There are plenty of free barcode image libraries. If you didn't find any you did not look very well.

Barcode 3 of 9 requires guard bars at the start and end of the code so the scanner knows where the code starts and ends. When printing the legend for a code 3 of 9, these guard bars are traditionally shown as asterisks. These asterisks are only for humans reading the legend, they are not part of the code and in fact an asterisk is not a legal code 3 of 9 character. If you remove the guard bars the scanner would not be able to read the barcode.